# Why do my events get lost? / Strange JavaScript Exception

Tags: java, gwt, gwtp

I was trying to send an event from a child presenter to a mother presenter. First i thought the events would simply get lost. I surrounded the fireEvent call with a try/catch block and get this error:

> (-:-) 2014-11-06 10:13:26,069 [ERROR] Exception caught: 
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) 
>    __gwt$exception: : Cannot read property 'b' of undefined
>       at Unknown.f2b(mdm-0.js@180:2440)
>       at Unknown.k2b(mdm-0.js@182:2442)
>       at Unknown.t2b(mdm-0.js@51:2448)

My original question got way too long and all the edits may have confused most people. So i constructed a totally stripped-down example, where the error still occurs. This will make it easier to track the error down (i hoped on this way i could solve it myself, but i can't).
I also included the imports now, just to be sure not to miss a detail.
I have mother presenter (which i also stripped down), which now nearly does not do anything:

```
package testproject.client.application.policies;

import testproject.client.application.ApplicationPresenter;
import testproject.client.application.policies.test.TestPolicyPresenterWidget;
import testproject.client.events.TestPolicyEvent;
import testproject.client.events.TestPolicyEvent.TestPolicyEventHandler;
import testproject.client.place.NameTokens;

import com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.client.Log;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.HasClickHandlers;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.Presenter;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.View;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.annotations.NameToken;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.annotations.ProxyEvent;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.annotations.ProxyStandard;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy.ProxyPlace;

public class PolicyPresenter extends
        Presenter<PolicyPresenter.MyView, PolicyPresenter.MyProxy> implements TestPolicyEventHandler {

    private TestPolicyPresenterWidget testPolicyDialog;

    @ProxyStandard
    @NameToken(NameTokens.policiesPage)
    public interface MyProxy extends ProxyPlace<PolicyPresenter> {
    }

    public interface MyView extends View {
        HasClickHandlers getTestPolicyButton();
    }

    @Inject
    PolicyPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, MyProxy proxy,
            TestPolicyPresenterWidget testPolicyDialog) {
        super(eventBus, view, proxy, ApplicationPresenter.SLOT_SetMainContent);
        this.testPolicyDialog = testPolicyDialog;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onBind() {
        super.onBind();

        addRegisteredHandler(TestPolicyEvent.TYPE, this);

        // Handler for add Policy Button
        getView().getTestPolicyButton().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {   
              public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Log.debug("Test Policy received click event");
                addToPopupSlot(testPolicyDialog);
              }
            });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onReveal() {
        super.onReveal();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        super.onReset();

    }

    @ProxyEvent
    @Override
    public void onTestPolicyEvent(TestPolicyEvent event) {
        Log.debug("TestPolicyCreatedEvent caught");
    }


}
```

I added the @ProxyEvent notation mentioned in the comments, just to make sure...

This view is now also very reduced:

```
package testproject.client.application.policies;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import testproject.client.model.ContainerPolicy;
import testproject.client.resources.MDMTCellTableResources;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.HasClickHandlers;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTable.Resources;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
import com.google.gwt.view.client.ProvidesKey;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.ViewImpl;

public class PolicyView extends ViewImpl implements PolicyPresenter.MyView {

    private static final int pageSize = 15;

    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, PolicyView> {
    }

    private static final ProvidesKey<ContainerPolicy> KEY_PROVIDER = new ProvidesKey<ContainerPolicy>() {
        @Override
        public Object getKey(ContainerPolicy item) {
            return item.getId();
        }
    };

    @UiField
    Button testPolicyButton;

    @UiField(provided=true)
    CellTable<ContainerPolicy> cellTable = new CellTable<ContainerPolicy>(pageSize, (Resources)GWT.create(MDMTCellTableResources.class), KEY_PROVIDER);

    public HasClickHandlers getTestPolicyButton() {
        return testPolicyButton;
    }


    public CellTable<ContainerPolicy> getCellTable() {
         return cellTable;
    }

    @Inject
    PolicyView(Binder uiBinder) {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}
```

So now when i click the button, another presenter is shown, using `addToPopupSlot(testPolicyDialog);`.

My child presenter (widget) is also totally stripped down now:
Presenter:

```
package testproject.client.application.policies.test;

import testproject.client.events.TestPolicyEvent;
import testproject.client.model.ClientModelProvider;

import com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.client.Log;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.CheckBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.HasUiHandlers;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.PopupView;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.PresenterWidget;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.annotations.ProxyEvent;

public class TestPolicyPresenterWidget extends PresenterWidget<TestPolicyPresenterWidget.MyView> implements
        TestPolicyUiHandlers {

    private final EventBus eventBus;

    public interface MyView extends PopupView, HasUiHandlers<TestPolicyUiHandlers> {
        CheckBox getEnabled();
        CheckBox getEnforced();
        TextBox getPolicyType();
        TextBox getContainerGroup();
    }

    @Inject
    TestPolicyPresenterWidget(EventBus eventBus, MyView view,
            ClientModelProvider clientModelProvider) {
        super(eventBus, view);
        this.eventBus = eventBus;

    }

    protected void onBind() {
        super.onBind();
        Log.debug("EventBus in NewPolicyPresenter is " + eventBus.toString()  + " with hashcode " + eventBus.hashCode());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onReveal() {
        super.onReveal();
    }


    @ProxyEvent
    @Override
    public void createPolicy() {
        try {
            Log.debug("Click event on ok Button in add policy dialog caught. ");
            Log.debug("Firing Event");
            eventBus.fireEvent(new TestPolicyEvent());
            Log.debug("Firing Event, without stating the eventBus:");
            fireEvent(new TestPolicyEvent());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error("Exception caught: ",e);
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
package testproject.client.application.policies.test;

import testproject.client.model.ContainerPolicy;

import com.google.gwt.editor.client.Editor;
import com.google.gwt.editor.client.SimpleBeanEditorDriver;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.CheckBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.PopupViewWithUiHandlers;

public class TestPolicyView extends PopupViewWithUiHandlers<TestPolicyUiHandlers> implements
        TestPolicyPresenterWidget.MyView, Editor<ContainerPolicy> {
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<PopupPanel, TestPolicyView> {
    }

    public interface Driver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<ContainerPolicy, TestPolicyView> {
    }


    @UiField
    CheckBox enabled;
    @UiField
    CheckBox enforced;
    @UiField
    TextBox policyType;

    @UiField
    TextBox containerGroup;

    @UiField
    Button okButton;
    @UiField
    Button cancelButton;

    @Inject
    TestPolicyView(Binder uiBinder,EventBus eventBus) {
        super(eventBus);
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }


    @UiHandler("okButton")
    void okButtonClicked(ClickEvent event) {
        getUiHandlers().createPolicy();

        hide();
    }

    @UiHandler("cancelButton")
    void cancelButtonClicked(ClickEvent event) {
        hide();
    }
    @Override
    public CheckBox getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public CheckBox getEnforced() {
        return enforced;
    }

    @Override
    public TextBox getPolicyType() {
        return policyType;
    }

    @Override
    public TextBox getContainerGroup() {
        return containerGroup;
    }
}
```

And, since it is somehow related to JS, the ui.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">

    <g:DialogBox modal="false">
        <g:caption>
            <b>Policy</b>
        </g:caption>
        <g:HTMLPanel>

            <div class="locked">
                <div class="lockedpanel float-wrapper container-edit">

                    <!-- Device block -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">

                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">Policy</h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-body">

                                <form class="form-bordered">
                                    <div class="form-group">

                                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Enabled</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <g:CheckBox ui:field="enabled" styleName="form-control input-sm"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Enforced</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <g:CheckBox ui:field="enforced" styleName="form-control input-sm" />
                                        </div>

                                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Policy Type</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <g:TextBox ui:field="policyType" styleName="form-control input-sm"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Container Group</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <g:TextBox ui:field="containerGroup" styleName="form-control input-sm"/>
                                        </div>

                                    </div><!-- form-group -->
                                </form>

                        </div><!-- panel-body -->
                    </div><!-- panel-default -->

                    <div class="float-right">
                        <g:Button ui:field="okButton" styleName="btn btn-primary btn-bordered">Ok</g:Button>
                        <g:Button ui:field="cancelButton" styleName="btn btn-primary btn-bordered">Cancel</g:Button>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- lockedpanel -->
            </div>

        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:DialogBox>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

I bind the presenters like this in the ApplicationModule:

```
package testproject.client.application;

...


public class ApplicationModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new UiModule());

        // Application Presenters
        bindPresenter(ApplicationPresenter.class, ApplicationPresenter.MyView.class, ApplicationView.class,
                      ApplicationPresenter.MyProxy.class);
...
        bindPresenter(PolicyPresenter.class, PolicyPresenter.MyView.class, PolicyView.class, PolicyPresenter.MyProxy.class);
        bindSingletonPresenterWidget(TestPolicyPresenterWidget.class, TestPolicyPresenterWidget.MyView.class,
                TestPolicyView.class);}
}
```

The error mentioned above happens when i try to access any object inside the createPolicy-method. E.g., when i call this:

```
    Log.debug("Click event on ok Button in add policy dialog caught. ");
    Log.debug("Firing Event");
    eventBus.fireEvent(new TestPolicyEvent());
```

i get the error. It does not matter if i use eventBus.fireEvent or fireEvent. It also happens when i try to access other objects. So i guess the problem is not really related to the event handling. But what could cause this?

Thanks for your help so far and for the time reading this...

Comment: Weird! Are you sure to inject the same eventBus instance in the view and in the Presenter?

Comment: i might be wrong. Are u using Gin/Guice here? if so, are u sure the eventbusses are the same one? i dont see your binding for the injection, so probably these are different instances?

Comment: Right and check your imports EventBus should be this one `com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus`and no `com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus`

Comment: It is com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.

Comment: @Terry: Correct. Shouldn't they be initialized by injecting them into the DevicesPresenter?

Comment: what u are (probably) missing is in your GinModule the binding

`bind(EventBus.class).to(SimpleEventBus.class).in(Singleton.class);`

So currently every injection a new instance will be created

Comment: They are the same, i updated the post. What kind of information can i add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your exception is being logged by the try/catch you added? When you use ViewWithUiHandlers,  you need to set your View's UiHandlers manually. In TestPolicyPresenterWidget, you need to add `view.setUiHandlers(this)` in its constructor, otherwise `getUiHandlers()` will return null in your view.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That really solved it. I turned blind and did not see i was missing that. And so the missing event overshadowed the underlying problem. Thank you all for helping me!